# How do I connect to a website port using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I'm coding in Python and I'm looking for a way to connect to a website port using sockets so that I can send commands to the server. My code is:

```
import socket

HOST = 'www.google.com'
PORT = 80

server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen(5)
```

This code is giving me an error "The requested address is not valid in its context". How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `bind` on Google's IP, which doesn't make sense because there isn't a network adapter connected to your computer with that IP (thus the error). You're mixing up creating a server and being a client connecting to a remote server. You want to `connect` to the Google server:

```
import socket

HOST = 'www.google.com'
PORT = 80

socket = socket.socket()
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))

# Send an HTTP GET request to request the page
socket.send(b"""
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com

""")
msg = socket.recv(8192)
print(msg)
```

Comment: does this connect to google.com?

Comment: @jeffreyneils Yes. Have you tried running it? I just fixed a bug in the HTTP request.

Comment: Yes it worked thanks bro. Is it possible to send files through this connection?

Comment: @jeffreyneils Send files to the Google server? If you mean just sending files over sockets, yes, that's really how all file transfers over the internet happen. You'd send the file as binary data using the same `send` method I'm using here.